# Can't change textview (broadcastreceiver)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to change my textview, but it doesn't work.

MainActivity:

```
public void changeTxt(String txt){
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiName);
    t.setText(txt);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
MainActivity ma;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ma= new MainActivity();
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    String txt = acCharge+"";
    ma.changeTxt(txt);
}
```

Comment: you need to register broadcast receiver

Comment: i've registred , but still doesnt work

Comment: `ma= new MainActivity();` I seriously doubt you should do this. Android creates activity objects for you. You can just use an Intent to ask android to create an activity for you.

Answer (score 0):

Call registerBroadCastReciever like this :

```
//BroadCastReciever variable in base activity or activity
        private BroadcastReceiver serviceBroadcastReceiver;         
//Register reciever method
        void registerBroadcastReceiver(){
        if (serviceBroadcastReceiver != null)
        {
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(this.serviceBroadcastReceiver);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getActivity()).registerReceiver(this.serviceBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("...BROADCAST_STR"));
            return;
        }
        this.serviceBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            public void onReceive(Context paramAnonymousContext, Intent paramAnonymousIntent)
            {
                //Recieve STH and call method like SetText() that initialize your textView text
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getActivity()).registerReceiver(this.serviceBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("...BROADCAST_STR"));
    }       //Then onResume & onPause methods in activity   
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(this.serviceBroadcastReceiver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**MyActivity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView wifi;
    private BateryReceiver bateryReceiver;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        wifi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiName);
        wifi.setText("nothing");

        bateryReceiver = new BateryReceiver(wifi);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(bateryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        unregisterReceiver(bateryReceiver);
    }
}
```

**BateryReceiver:** (create new class if you don't have)

```
public class BateryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final TextView textView;

    public BateryReceiver(TextView textView)
    {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean ac = (chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC);
        boolean usb = (chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC);

        String plugSource = (ac == true)? "AC" : "USB";

        if(isCharging)
            textView.setText("charging: " + isCharging + " by " + plugSource);
        else
            textView.setText("not charging");
    }
}
```

It should be working.